# Component's html included the last HTML

Tags: html, angular

I have problem with HTML like the images below:

Error :

[image: Error problem]

I clicked a button to move to the page with path: /page/:beecow, the last HTML will show if  '/page/:beecow' have an error. The last HTML is 'market' in app-routing

I'm using angular version 4.3.5

```
// Here is my app-routing
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
    path: 'page', // Navigate to here
    loadChildren: './page/page.module#PageModule'
    },
    {
    path: 'market',
    loadChildren: './market/market.module#MarketModule'
    },
    {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
    }
    ];

    @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }

// Here is my page-routing
    const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '', component: PageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
    {
    path: 'upload-product',
    component: ProductComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    data: {
    authorities: ['ROLE_STORE'],
    pageTitle: 'beecow.store.item.productTitle'
    },
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    canDeactivate: [NavigationService]
    },
    {
    path: ':beecow', // if The component have error, html expanded
    component: ManageItemComponent
    }
    ]
    }];

    @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class PageRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for PageComponent? It looks like you have a null value with a field named x that you're trying to access.

Comment: Yup! I want to show you while I had an error with code, the HTML will show like that. 'x' just {{abc.x}} in HTML

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to know why it's null, but, yeah, the value isn't initialized when you're calling {{abc.x}}